Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-(\cos \sqrt{x})\cdots(\cos \sqrt{n x})}{\sin x+\cdots+\sin n x}$.
Consider the limit:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-(\cos \sqrt{x})\cdots(\cos \sqrt{n x})}{\sin x+\cdots+\sin n x}.
\end{equation}
I tried to use this formula for the denominator:
\begin{equation}
\sin x+\sin 2 x+\cdots+\sin n x=\frac{\sin \frac{(n+1) x}{2} \sin \frac{n x}{2}}{\sin \frac{x}{2}}.
\end{equation}
This can be replaced using equivalent infinitesimal, but I don't know how to handle the numerator.

Have you learned about Taylor expansion?

I think you probably meant $x\to 0^+$ otherwise the square root won't make sense in this context. BTW you have asked this question on Quora as well and Enrico Gregorio has solved it there.

Try dividing numerator and denominator by $x$. And also note that the expression in numerator is of the form $1-abc\dots$ where each of $a, b, c\dots $tends to $1$ and hence we can write $1-abc \dots =1-a+a(1-bc\dots) $.

$$L=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1 - (\cos\sqrt{x})(\cos\sqrt{2x})\dots(\cos\sqrt{nx})}{\sin x+\sin 2x + \dots + \sin nx}$$
Substituting the Taylor series for $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ (We can discard the higher-order terms):
$$L=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1 - \left(1-\frac{\sqrt{x}^2}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2x}^2}{2}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{nx}^2}{2}\right)}{x+2x+3x+\dots+nx}$$
$$L=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1 - \left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{2x}{2}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac{nx}{2}\right)}{x+2x+3x+\dots+nx}$$
$$L=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{2}(x+2x+\dots+nx)}{x+2x+\dots+nx}=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}}$$
